# Running Bower from TeamCity?

Tags: node.js, teamcity, bower

I have a team city build on Windows with 3 steps. I would like to include a bower step to install all dependencies from the bower.json in the project rather than checking in the lib folder.

Current steps are:

1. NPM ( install, install grunt-cli, install grunt)
2. Grunt
3. karma

I'm not very familiar with node or teamcity and tried to do the following. In (1) added "install bower". Added a new step after (1) running node.js with "bower --force-latest" but was struggling with various errors. Please can someone give me a step by step explanation of how to get bower running or whether I should?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
1) installed grunt and bower onto the server
2) updated the PATH environment variables to include bower
3) rebooted the build box
4) added a command line build step running bower from the correct project working directory: bower install -f
```

it works! all bower packages installed. karma unit tests then work without moaning about dependencies! I can now remove the lib folder from the commit...